# Can an EventListener be removed by nullifying its callback function?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I was wondering if an event listener can be removed by nullifying its callback function?

Simplified Example:

```
var somefunction = function() {
  // some code
}
window.addEventListener(eventType, somefunction, false);
```

Now, will setting `somefunction = null;` remove the above EventListener, or will it simply turn it into a zombie EventListener?

The actual code is used in a Firefox (overlay-type) Addon and I was contemplating alternative methods of (automatically) removing EventListeners on `unload` event, other than the obvious:

```
window.removeEventListener(eventType, somefunction, false);
```

**Update:** Please note that this is part of a code for a Firefox addon. The eventType in this instance is `'popupshowing'` which can not be nullified as it would disrupt browser functions.

Thank you in advance for your help
Looking forward to (alternative) suggestions

Comment: i dont think setting callback function to null will remove eventlistener, but setting eventType = null (in your case) should remove the event listener

Comment: Thank you. I will add clarification to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeEventListener` is the way to go.

Also, you don't actually *nullify* the function by setting some variable to `null`. The variable has assigned just a reference (to a non-POD object, like a function). To illustrate this, consider the following:

```
var a = function() { alert("called"); };
setTimeout(a, 1000); // Will still alert!

var b = a;

a = null; // What you called `nullify`....
console.log(this.a, "a" in this); // null, true
delete this.a; // Actually remove the property from the global scope.
// `a` is really dead at this point!

b(); // will still alert, too.
```

If you want to avoid some `removeEventListener` calls, I'd use some helper function(s):

```
let { addEventListenerUnload, removeEventListenerUnload } = (function() {
  let tracked = [];
  addEventListener("unload", function removeTracked() {
    removeEventListener("unload", removeTracked);
    for (let t of tracked) {
      try {
        removeEventListener(t.type, t.fn, t.capture);
      }
      catch (ex) {}
    }
    tracked.length = 0;
  });
  return {
    addEventListenerUnload: function(type, fn, capture) {
      addEventListener(type, fn, capture);
      tracked.push({type: type, fn: fn, capture: capture});
    },
    removeEventListenerUnload: function(type, fn, capture) {
      tracked = tracked.filter(e => e.type != type || e.fn != fn || e.capture != capture);
      removeEventListener(type, fn, capture);
    }
  };
})();
```

(Includes some ECMA-6 stuff that Firefox supports, but which you could easily convert. Also, `removeEventListenerUnload` might not be needed at all, so you might omit it. Also, when using this in overlay script make sure to give it unique names to avoid clashes with other code).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In fact, I am creating an array of objects (One for each listener listing its parameters) and use that later for `removeEventListener` and it works (although difficult to measure its performance on `unload` but I was looking to simplify it further by exploring other possibilities. :)

Comment: You know, the usual way to thank people here on SO is to upvote and/or accept their answers... Just saying ;) But please do not take this as a request to vote my particular answer here: Of course, you're free to vote as you please.

Comment: Will do so immediately :)

Answer (score 1):

i dont think setting callback function to null will remove eventlistener, you'll still have eventlistener attached, you could use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) or set the `eventType` to null, like:

```
window.eventType = null;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will add clarification to the original post. :)